# Firebase suddenly giving permissions error for accessing firebase storage

Tags: firebase, permissions, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase functions/firestore/storage.

My functions are set up so that they are called from the web-app without being signed in. On the function side, I access the storage bucket for the project, which has its security rules set to:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

so that only the functions can access it. I never had problems until today, when I wrote a new function that is suddenly generating the error:

> Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to MYPROJECTNAMEHERE.appspot.com/FOLDERNAMEHERE/EXAMPLEFILE.JSON

Every other function works fine, except any new functions I create are having this issue. I'm confused, the admin library is setup properly, and I've even tried manually setting the config for initializing the admin app.

Any idea on what's going on here? I tried updating the permissions in the bucket/service accounts but no luck.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide an MCVE so we can actually see what's going on.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, do you still have this issue? could you provide the minimal reproducible example as Doug mentioned on the previous comment?